# Dpkg is trying to install a deleted deb file and errors appear

Tags: 17.04

It Shows a Error That Dependicies Will Not Be Installed But I Cant Install Other Applications

[image: image]]

Comment: Please don't use screenshots of text. Instead, paste the text into the editor, select it, and press the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: Did you try what you are told to try at the end of the output?

Answer (score 0):

You have two packages half installed. Every time you run apt or dpkg it tries to finish the install on those packages. Try:

```
sudo apt-get --purge gens
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Then try to install `mupen64plus`